# Need Help Generating a Report That Can Be Sorted by Last Activity Not Including List Email

Tags: reporting

I am trying to generate a report that will generate a list of contacts sorted by last activity other than list email.

I can generate a report showing the latest activity not including list emails.  This is lacking because it is a list of activities, not contacts, so it doesn't include those with no call activity, and it also gets cluttered by multiple activities with the same contact.

We have just recently started logging individual calls, and need to track who hasn't been called, and after that who has been the longest since being called.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have continued to search, and may have discovered that this is impossible at this point according to this ideaexchange article: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdgt0UAB/report-filter-only-the-most-recent-activity-for-each-parent-record